# Long range wireless mouse and keyboard or alternatives (through wall)

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

What would be the best way to connect a computer or 2; that are in a different room from the video?
I did run the HDMI and network cable from the computer through a wall plug; but I can't run a USB through the wall, since the cable would be quite long, so I tried with a wireless keyboard and mouse, but the range is not that powerful.

As options I have either a long USB cable, risking signal degrading; buy a better mouse+keyboard wireless combo or get a box that is able to carry HDMI+LAN+USB somehow through the wall. Did I forget something?

Comment: What type of mouse you've tried, there are big differences! If you need to control the computer from that room only, then I would consider moving it there and connect display through lan.

Comment: Find a shop which lets you return items for a full refund, buy a few different sets and keep the one which works best.

Answer (score 3):

Long USB cables have repeaters in the middle & don't cause any significant degradation.

I have 15m cables in use here for remoting keyboards/mice [with bluetooth dongles on the ends of some] & also tethered shooting on my camera - all with zero issues, even pulling hi-res video files over them, camera to computer.

You can get them up to 30m - [example Amazon search](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=30m+usb) - with two repeaters, though I've never tested these personally.

From [YourCableStore - USB Cable Length Limitations And How To Break Them](http://www.yourcablestore.com/USB-Cable-Length-Limitations-And-How-To-Break-Them_ep_42-1.html)

> **Maximum length of USB active (repeater) cable:**
>
> This number depends if you are using a regular cable with an active
>   cable or not. If you are not using a regular cable, then the maximum
>   active cable length for USB 2.0 is 30 meters (98 feet and 5 inches)
>   and the maximum recommended length for USB 3.0/3.1 is 18 meters (about
>   59 feet). If you are using a regular cable (max length of 5 meters for
>   2.0 and max length of 3 meters for 3.0/3.1) with an active cable, then the maximum length for USB 2.0 is 25 meters (about 82 feet) and the
>   maximum recommended length for USB 3.0/3.1 is 15 meters (about 49
>   feet).

Answer (score 2):

I just installed a 50-meter Bluetooth USB adapter in a dental office so the mouse and keyboard could be used in a different room from the computer. It works. So, my answer would be high powered Bluetooth. The adapter was $23 from Amazon.